# Retrieve the Url parameter from a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, hottowel

I need to access the parameters of the current url with Durandal.

Actually from the *activate* function, I'm able to do so:

```
function activate(routeData) {
    var type = routeData.type;
    var id = parseInt(routeData.id);
}
```

and retrieve the following parameters ***project*** and ***1*** of my url:

```
http://localhost:3231/#/next/project/1
```

But how can I do so from another function within my view model?

**NB:** I need also to retrieve ***next*** from the url.

Answer (score 1):

```
var params = window.location.hash.split('/');
```

Comment: I was thinking more of something using durandal router ?

Answer (score 0):

Define an action param in your router.map function

something like:

```
 router.map([
  { route: '', title:'Your title', moduleId: ':action/project/:id', nav: true }
])
```

So you can access the value in your activate function via

```
routeData.action
```

Comment: Yes, i'm able to access it from my activate function, but I want to access from another function ?

Comment: Store the infomration in your view like this.action = routeData.action